# How to run appium and android emulator at the same time, in vagrant machine

Tags: android, testing, android-emulator, vagrant, appium

I'm currently running tests for an android application in my local machine, for this I use appium and an android emulator, these two have to run at the same time in order to execute the tests. Now I'm trying to run these tests in a Vagrant machine and I could not find a way to run appium and android emulator at the same time in Vagrant, does any of you have an answer to this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple instances of Appium if they use different ports. So you'd have iOS run on one and Android run on another.  Just change the host to match the Appium server's port. You can specify which port you want with -p if you're running via command line.

For example on command line you'd run:
`appium -p 4723` in one window and on another
`appium -p 4725`

Then in your code you'd have something like this:

`IOSDriver idriver = new IOSDriver(new Url("127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps));`
`AndroidDriver adriver = new AndroidDriver(new Url("127.0.0.1:4725/wd/hub", caps));`

where caps is your desiredCapabilities. Hope this helps.